# Idompotency in java restful web service

Tags: jpa, restful-architecture

I am trying to understand concept of idompotent method in context of restful API.But I am not able to really grasp it. Why is it that POST method is not idompotent while PUT is?
I am confused because in use case for my PUT API I am using JPA's merge method which creates a new entity in DB if one doesn't exist. So my PUT API behaves like a POST API in some scenarios.So does it mean that PUT becomes non-idompotent now?
I think I don't even understand basics of the subject here.

Answer (score 3):

You're correct that PUT and POST have similar effects in that they can both create a resource. But they also sometimes behave differently, and it's in that difference that one is idempotent and the other is not.

A request method is said to be *idempotent* if it has the same effect being received a single time as it has if it is received twice, thrice, or n-times in a row.

Consider the Facebook *like*. *Like* is idempotent; if I tell Facebook that I *like* an item once, or twice, or thrice, it should all amount to the same effect: a single like on that item from my user.

Now suppose I send Facebook a *like*, but the response times out in my browser. I don't know if Facebook got my like or not. Is it OK for me to re-send my like? The answer is yes! Even if they got my first like, it's no harm for me to send it a second or third time.

On the other hand, consider a Facebook *comment*. Commenting is not idempotent. If I send the same comment on an item once, then the result is one comment on the item. If I send the same comment thrice, then the result is three comments on the item. If I send a comment to a post and my browser times out, is it OK for me to re-send my comment? The answer is no: I should probably refresh the page to see if my comment was added or not before I try to send it again.

That's the main point of designating methods as idempotent/non-idempotent: if the client experiences a response timeout on an idempotent method, it knows that it's safe to send that request again; if the client experiences a response timeout on a non-idempotent method, then it doesn't know whether it's safe to send that request again.

With that in mind, let's look at PUT and POST.

POST is used to add a resource to a collection. Typically, you would POST a resource to an endpoint like '/api/students/'. That *creates* a new student. If you POST the student Jimmy one time to '/api/students/' then you've got one new Jimmy. But if you post the student Jimmy thrice to '/api/students/', then you've got three new Jimmies! That's not idempotency.

PUT is used to create or update a resource *at a known uri*. So suppose your individual students have uris '/api/students/1', '/api/students/2', etc. If you PUT Jimmy to '/api/students/43', then the result is that Jimmy is now at '/api/students/43'; if there was already a student 43 then that student was replaced, if there wasn't then one was created. If you PUT Jimmy to '/api/students/43' again, then the effect is STILL that Jimmy is at '/api/students/43'. You can PUT Jimmy to '/api/students/43' n-times, and the effect won't be any different than just doing it once. That's idempotency.

Comment: Thanks a lot JASchilz.